# java.lang.reflect.Method invoke() argument Type mismatch exception

Tags: java, reflection

I am dynamically consuming a webservice by JAX-WS API. Instantiating service class and invoking by web service by reflection API.

Though the expected and actual argument is same its getting "Argument type mismatch" Exception.

Quick help is appreciated.

```
Class<?>[] paramTypes = serviceClassMethod.getParameterTypes();
System.out.println("Expected Param Class : "+paramTypes[0].getName());
System.out.println("Actual Param Class : "+reqVals[0].getClass());
System.out.println("Expected number : "+paramTypes.length);
System.out.println("Actual number : "+reqVals.length);
Object wsResponse = serviceClassMethod.invoke(service, reqVals);
System.out.println("Invocation successful...");
```

Output:

```
Expected Param Class : com.bla.bla.ws.User
Actual Param Class : class com.bla.bla.ws.User
Expected number : 1
Actual number : 1
```

Comment: Might be a classloading issue. The JRE treats the same class loaded by different classloaders as different class. How do you create your parameter object?

Comment: In addition to my previous comment, you can test this using `paramTypes[0].equals(reqVals[0].getClass())`. If this is not true, you most likely have the mentioned problem.

Comment: Thanks, yes that was a classloader issue.

Comment: Allright, glad it worked. I'll post it as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a classloading issue. The JRE treats the same class loaded by different classloaders as different class. It depends on how you create your parameter object. You can test this using:

```
paramTypes[0].equals(reqVals[0].getClass())
```

If this is not true, you are using two different classes.

A solution would be to ensure your parameter object is created with the correct class using `paramTypes[0].newInstance();`